# SwiftUI Menu change items text size

Tags: ios, swiftui, menu

I am trying to increase the text size of each Button inside a `Menu`. This is my playground where I try to change the text size:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct Sample: View {
    @State var selectedIndex = 0
    private var inputs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Text(String(inputs[selectedIndex]))
                .font(.system(size: 30))

            Menu {
                ForEach(0 ..< inputs.count, id: \.self) {
                    let index = $0
                    let text = "\(inputs[index])"
                    Button(action: {
                        selectedIndex = index
                    }, label: {
                        Text(text)
                            .font(.system(size: 30))
                    })
                }
            } label: {
                Label("", image: "")
                    .labelStyle(TitleOnlyLabelStyle())
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity) // That way we have the same touch area.
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 500, height: 500)
    }
}


PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(Sample())
```

However, setting the font size on the text element itself does not change it:

```
Text(text)
    .font(.system(size: 30))
```

Are there any tricks / other solutions to increase the text size of each element?

[image]

---

Regarding the possibility of a Custom Menu, here's some background information.

This is my current screen where I have a list of items that resembles a Yatzy block:

[image]

Each row can be clickable. Each row is a View. Hence each View has their own `Menu` and will be shown then the row is clicked. Through the menu the score can be selected. When tapping anywhere else the Menu will disappear. Note that the following regarding the Menu can change:

- number of items (should be scrollable if necessary)
- positioning (smartly, if it has enough space to the bottom or top part, and if it does not fit to the center)

Here are a few scenarios:

[image]

1. Clicking on ones, everything fits
2. Clicking on sixes, the same
3. Clicking on Three of a kind, many options hence taking up almost all the space (it looks like Menu has a max height of 70-80% of the screen!)
4. Clicking on Full house, enough space to show above
5. Clicking on Yatzy, makes no sense to show full screen since we're so close to the end of the list

I don't actually know the internal calculations for this positioning of the `Menu` but it feels and looks very natural and is probably the trickiest to get right.

Comment: You cannot, at least right now. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69664413/5133585

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is no easy way to increase the font size of a standard `Menu`.

As a workaround, you can build your own custom menu and this can then be styled any way you like. This gives you much more control over appearance and behavior. On the other hand, nothing comes for free, so any functionality you want to have needs to be implemented explicitly.

Based on your comment and the screenshot you provided after you tried my first attempt at an answer, I am now assuming the following:

- the super-sized menu is only going to be used in one specific context, it does not need to be aimed at general-purpose use
- it will always be positioned top-center of the main content
- there may be quite a lot of menu items, so they might need to be scrolled
- the items might contain an `HStack` with `Spacer`
- the items have striped backgrounds, so dividers between the items are not needed.

Here is a new attempt to provide a solution for this specific use case.

- `BigMenu` displays a group of menu items which are supplied as a `ViewBuilder` closure.
- The menu is intended to be shown as an overlay over the main content, alignment `.top`.
- The items can be scrolled if there is insufficient height to show them all.

```swift
struct BigMenu<Content: View>: View {
    @ViewBuilder let content: () -> Content

    var menuBody: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            content()
        }
    }

    var body: some View {

        // Use a GeometryReader to measure the space available
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            let maxHeight = proxy.size.height

            // Use a hidden version of the menu to determine the ideal height
            menuBody
                .hidden()
                .overlay(alignment: .top) {

                    // Show the visible version inside a ScrollView
                    ScrollView {
                        menuBody
                            .background(.regularMaterial)
                            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 13))
                    }
                    .frame(maxHeight: maxHeight)
                    .scrollBounceBehavior(.basedOnSize)
                    .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.2), radius: 40)
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        }
        .transition(
            .scale(0.01, anchor: .top)
            .animation(.easeOut(duration: 0.25))
        )
    }
}
```

The example below shows how the menu can be used for menu items that are more elaborate than in your original example.

- The parent container is a `VStack` containing the page heading and a `ZStack` for the main content.
- The menu is applied as an overlay to the `ZStack`. So it appears below the page heading.
- The `onTapGesture` that toggles the flag for showing the menu is attached to the `ZStack` too. This means, tapping anywhere on the main content will show the menu, tapping the main content anywhere outside of the visible menu will hide it again.
- A catchall `.onTapGesture` is applied to the parent container (the `VStack`). This forcibly hides the menu. This takes effect if the header area is tapped when the menu is showing.
- The width of the menu is constrained by setting a `maxWidth` on the individual menu items.

```swift
struct Sample: View {
    @State var selectedIndex = 0
    private var names = ["hare", "tortoise", "dog", "cat", "lizard", "bird", "ant", "ladybug", "fossil.shell", "fish"]
    @State private var showingMenu = false

    @ViewBuilder
    private var menuItems: some View {
        ForEach(Array(names.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, name in
            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                Text(name)
                Spacer()
                Text("\(index)")
                    .font(.body)
                    .foregroundStyle(.gray)
                Image(systemName: name)
                    .frame(maxWidth: 30)
            }
            .font(.system(size: 30))
            .padding()
            .frame(maxWidth: 300)
            .background { Color(white: index % 2 == 0 ? 0.9 : 1) }
            .onTapGesture {
                selectedIndex = index
                showingMenu = false
            }
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Text("Page Heading")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .padding()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(.mint)
            ZStack {
                HStack(spacing: 40) {
                    Text("(\(selectedIndex))")
                    Text("\(names[selectedIndex])")
                    Image(systemName: names[selectedIndex])
                }
                .font(.system(size: 30))
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .contentShape(Rectangle()) // make empty space sensitive to tap
            .onTapGesture { showingMenu.toggle() }
            .overlay(alignment: .top) {
                if showingMenu {
                    BigMenu { menuItems }
                }
            }
        }
        .onTapGesture { showingMenu = false }
    }
}
```

[image: Animation]

Comment: This is a good starting. I have an entire list of those clickable numbers. [Here's a screenshot](https://is1-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/PurpleSource126/v4/e8/89/39/e88939a4-87a7-980a-334c-ac8a01759963/16b86a62-d0ea-4179-b2e3-8361fa15c1fe_iPad_Pro__U002812.9-inch_U0029__U00286th_generation_U0029-02.png/626x0w.webp)
With your current solution the overlaying does not quite work since when I click on one, the overlay is shown but everything is behind the other numbers. Also when clicking somewhere else on the screen the menu does not disappear. All of this comes for free with Apple's Menu.

Comment: @Niklas Answer completely revised.

Comment: Look, you've spent so much time on this. I'm giving you the points but it's not what I want, but this is my fault since I didn't describe it well. For next time, I've updated my description with hopefully all the information.

Comment: @Niklas Wow, appreciate the early bounty, thanks! Unfortunately, it does look like it's been an exercise in misunderstood requirements, I think it was closer to what you wanted before I revised it all. You might like to consider showing the custom menu as a layer in a `ZStack` (instead of as an overlay), with position dependent on the row used to launch it. However, I can't help thinking that the list of numbers are not using the screen space very efficiently. Have you considered a grid-style layout for the numbers, like when you order Nespresso coffee (see nesprosso.com)?

Comment: Yeah I might as well just choose to change the entire input UI/UX.

Answer (score 0):

The "Menu" component and its subcomponents are rendered using the default style provided by the system, which may not be overridden. I suggest you create a custom MenuView, for example:

```
struct CustomMenu: View {
    let items: [String]
    let onSelect: (String) -> Void
    @Binding var isExpanded: Bool

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
            ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                Button(action: {
                    self.onSelect(item)
                    self.isExpanded.toggle()
                }) {
                    Text(item)
                        .font(.system(size: 60)) // Set your custom font size here
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color.white)
        .cornerRadius(5)
        .shadow(radius: 5)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
    }
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
struct Sample: View {
    @State private var selectedIndex: Int = 0
    @State private var isMenuExpanded: Bool = false
    private var inputs = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.isMenuExpanded.toggle()
            }) {
                HStack {
                    Text("Select Option")
                        .font(.system(size: 20))
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.down")
                        .rotationEffect(.degrees(isMenuExpanded ? 180 : 0))
                }
            }

            if isMenuExpanded {
                CustomMenu(items: inputs, onSelect: { selectedItem in
                    if let index = inputs.firstIndex(of: selectedItem) {
                        selectedIndex = index
                    }
                }, isExpanded: $isMenuExpanded)
            }

            Spacer()
            Text("Selected: \(inputs[selectedIndex])")
                .font(.system(size: 30))
        }
        .padding().frame(width: 500, height: 500)
    }
}
```

Comment: How would one get the overlaying effect and the almost identical visual traits of `Menu` with your implementation? Right now the CustomMenu is squeezed inside the views, which is not what I'd want.