# How to enlarge the picker dropdown size and display it only 7 at a time(need to scroll to view other value)?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I currently working on a SwiftUI project and I am using Picker to select age. However, the dropdown choices is too small compares to iPad size which makes it not visually pleasing. The dropdown choices also appears in descending order. I want it to be in ascending order.

Below is the code that I have implemented. And how it looks and what I am trying to achieve.

[image: Screenshot]

```
import SwiftUI
struct AgeSelect: View {
    let consent: Bool
    let stroopOrFlanker: Bool // Flanker = true  Stroop = false
    @State private var age: Int = 0
    @State private var stroop = false
    @State private var flanker = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Color.white.ignoresSafeArea(.all)[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6rX4.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6lOD.png)
            VStack {
                Text("Select your age :")
                    .font(.custom("GlacialIndifference-Bold", size: 80))
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .offset(y:-70)
                
                    Menu {
                        Picker("Age", selection: $age) {
                            ForEach(4..<100, id: \.self) {
                                Text("\($0) years old")
                            }
                        }
                    } label: {
                        HStack {
                            Text("\(age) years old")
                                .font(.system(size: 50))
                            
                            Image(systemName: "chevron.up.chevron.down")
                                .font(.system(size: 40))
                        }
                    }
                
                Button(action: {
                    setStroopFlanker()
                    // add age to database here MUST add 4 to age to record correctly
                }) {
                    Text("Confirm")
                        .font(.custom("GlacialIndifference-Bold", size: 60))
                        .padding()
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .background(.purple)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                }
                .offset(y: 100)
                .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $flanker) {
                    let Psaver = ParticipantSaver(experimentID: 1, versionID: 0, isMultilingual: 0, participantTbl: nil, age: age)  //needs to be swapped out for input by participant
                    let _ = Psaver.insert()
                    if age <= 8 {
                        FriendlyCognitive.flanker(consent: consent, isChildVersion: true)
                    } else {
                        FriendlyCognitive.flanker(consent: consent, isChildVersion: false)
                    }
                }
                .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $stroop){
                    Stroop(consent: consent)
                }
            }
        }
    }
        
    func setStroopFlanker(){
        if stroopOrFlanker == true{
            flanker = true
        }
        else {
            stroop = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ***No***. From a UI design perspective, an app designed for iPads is not supposed to just "make everything bigger". I find a large menu like this "not visually pleasing". Menus certainly should remain their original size (which is why Apple does not allow you to scale menus). Rethink your design. Perhaps you can add other elements to the UI to make use of the large screen of iPads?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue of ordering, just apply `.menuOrder(.fixed)` to the `Menu`.

Regarding size of menu items, diverging from the Apple design is probably a bad idea and there is no easy way to do it (as *Sweeper* already explained). If you really want to take that approach then you probably need to build your own menu. The post [SwiftUI Menu change items text size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77741856/20386264) might help.

Alternatively, if you use `.wheel` as picker style then the options can be made larger, see the answer to [SwiftUI Picker: The padding of content in Picker does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77781895/20386264) for details. However, when I tried it, I found that it didn't work when the `Picker` is nested inside a `Menu`.